# Resharper Ctrl + - opposite shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Resharper provides a great feature: Jump to previous focused method.

This can be caused by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> shortcut

What is the opposite shortcut, jump to the next method?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, go to `Tools`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Keyboard`. In the box that says 'Press shortcut keys:' press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and see what's in the 'Shortcut currently use by:' box. (Mine says View.NavigateBackward (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> (Global))). In the 'Show commands containing:' box type in 'View.Navigate' and you will see 'View.NavigateForward'. Select that and in the 'Shortcut for selected command: box will be the keyboard shortcut (On mine it's: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>(Global))

Comment: Thank You! You right the shortcut is "Ctrl + Shift + -"

Answer (score 0):

Here is key combination  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>